# Multiple async waits for observables in Angular

Tags: angular, asynchronous, concurrency

I have a few calls to make in my project to gather the data I need to process and show to the user.

Let's say I have a `Geolocate` call, a `GetProvinces` call, a `ReverseGeocode` call and finally I need to write some code to process the data.

Now here's the thing: `Geolocate` and `GetProvinces` are independent, while `ReverseGeocode` depends on `Geolocate` data, and the final bit of code depends on data from `GetProvinces` and `ReverseGeocode`.

[image]

The first thing I did was nest the calls (`Geolocate` -> `ReverseGeocode` -> `GetProvinces` -> process data) but this was wasting too much time when I could have been making various calls at the same time.

Investigating I found out about [forkJoin](https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-multiple-http-requests-with-rxjs) with which I could make the `Geolocate` and `GetProvinces` calls run simultaneously, but then I would have to wait for the slowest of them to finish before I could make the `ReverseGeocode`call and finally process the data, when I'd like it to happen as soon as `Geolocate` gets a response, and I don't know which will take the longest time.

Using Observables, is there some way to schedule these async calls so that I'm not wasting time, considering these constraints?

EDIT: should have mentioned that I'm trying to not nest calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Join **Geolocate** and **Reverse Geocode** into a unique observable, for example with switch map and does a forkJoin with **GetProvinces**

I suggest have a cache service, [example](https://hackernoon.com/angular-simple-in-memory-cache-service-on-the-ui-with-rxjs-77f167387e39)